# Putting shiny_iconLink and checkboxInput on the same line in Shiny

Tags: checkbox, shiny, icons, inline

I'm trying to put a shiny_iconlink() with a modal on the same line as a checkboxInput. I've been messing around with div classes and ids, but nothing seems to be working.

```html
fluidRow(
  column(width = 4,
         span(id="icon", shiny_iconlink()),
         checkboxInput("checkbox", "get me inline"),
         bsModal("modal", "title", "icon", "content")
        )
)
```

Comment: You can just use `fluidRow` and `column`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SBista suggested, you use `fluidRow` and `column`. [This article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) about Shiny application layout is helpful, especially the section on the [fluid grid system](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html#grid-layouts-in-depth).

Try this out:

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)    
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 1,
               span(id="icon", shiny_iconlink())),
        column(width = 2,
               checkboxInput("checkbox", "get me inline"),
               bsModal("modal", "title", "icon", "content")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```